# angularjs string variable to html element using sanitize

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-sanitizing, ngsanitize

AngularJS code:

```
$scope.checking="<div style="color:red;">check</div>";
```

HTML code:

```
<p ng-bind-html="checking"></p>
```

so i used $sanitize for this one and the ng-bind-html directive to get the job done.

So the result in html page is:

```
check
```

and the above should come in red color

i got the output but the string 'check' does not come in red! the style tag is ignored! how can i do it? do i use interpolate?

Any way to do it? hopefully its simple... AngularJS experts please help!

Answer (score 3):

[**$sanitize**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) Sanitizes an html string by stripping all potentially dangerous tokens.

So do use [**$sce**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service method to make it trusted `html` using `trustAsHtml` method.

`$scope.checking= $sce.trustAsHtml("<div style="color:red;">check</div>")`;